# How can I adjust the cross tab order using a formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I am trying to organize my cross tab labels in a specified order. The table shows students that have left the school by grade level and year. Grade level is dependant on an if - then formula because the database does not have the grade that students left the school. The grade level is calculated by subtracting the withdrawal year from their grad year and then applying a text string based on the result.

When I try to adjust to a specific order there is no option to select the individual groupings as my formula is not available in the common tab. The labels in the column are accurate but just out of order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to Crystal reports. Perhaps I am not understanding how a cross tab works or perhaps there are problems with my formula.

[current view of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oglg.png)

[Cross tab expert view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoZUx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to change the formula that generates the labels so they sort alphabetically as you wish. You can pad the numbers with a zero so that '1' becomes '01' or prepend the text with a counter (01., 02., etc.).